# Verify that $I$ and $X$ are negatively correlated.

Tags: probability, statistics, correlation, simulation, parameter-estimation

In certain situations, a random variable $X$ with known mean is simulated to
obtain an estimate of $P(X \leq a)$ for some constant given $a$. The simple estimator of a simulation for a run is $I = I (X \leq a)$.

Verify that $I$ and $X$ are negatively correlated.

My approach:

By definition $$Corr(X,I)=\frac{Cov(X,I)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$$
Then the only chance for the correlation to be negative is when covariance is negative.
$$Cov(X,I)=E[XI]-E[X]E[I]$$

I'm not sure on how to interpret the random variable $I$ and its expected value. Any suggestion would be great!!

Comment: A small note:  That formula for $Corr(X, I)$ should be
$$Corr(X, I) = \dfrac{Cov(X, I)}{\sqrt{Var(X) Var(I)}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\mathsf{E}I=\mathsf{P}(X\le a)$. When $\mathsf{P}(X\le a)=0$, the covariance between $X$ and $I$ is zero. Otherwise,

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X,I)&=\mathsf{E}X1\{X\le a\}-\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{P}(X\le a) \\
&= \mathsf{E}[X\mid X\le a]\mathsf{P}(X\le a)-\mathsf{E}X\mathsf{P}(X\le a) \\
&=(\mathsf{E}[X\mid X\le a]-\mathsf{E}X)\mathsf{P}(X\le a)\le 0.
\end{align}